# why does my tablet say insufficient space?

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory

I have a few apps, but this tablet is new and I want more apps. Every time I say download, it says I have insufficient space. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings>storage and take a look at what you have for space.  Some devices come with very little to start with (4gb) while others have buckets (64gb).  Downloading a few movies or games (or loading a big music library) can push a 4gb device to its limit fairly quickly.

If you've checked settings and see that you have very little available space, doing some app housecleaning will obviously help.  Some devices will accept an external microsd card, so you have a relatively inexpensive way put a bunch more room on your tablet.

If you've checked setting and there is a lot of available space left, then we need to explore other options.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest checking what it says in your storage settings to see what you have available for space, and what is taking up the most space. Your media files, downloads, or cached data may be taking up more space than you expect.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts SE.  Unfortunately, this does not consist of an answer, this is something more for the comments section.  I know you don't have the reputation to add comments yet, but try answering questions, or asking them to raise your reputation.